# JSON - How do I add object in an objectArray string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm kinda new to javascript. Few days ago I started a node js project. I had some javascript problems, but already answered questions helped me to get by. Although, there is an issue that I can't find a solution for it. My code is this:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'post' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10", function(err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var i;
                var statuses = "[";
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    username = result[i].poster;
                    message = result[i].message_text;
                    id = result[i].id;
                    post_type = result[i].post_type;
                    reply_to = result[i].reply_to;
                    
                    statuses = statuses + '{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"' +username+ '","id":' + id + ',"m":"' + message + '"},'
                    
                }

                statuses = statuses.substring(0, statuses.length - 1);
                statuses = statuses + ']'

                ws.send('{"action":"Load statuses","statuses":' + statuses + '}');      

            });
```

After the **for loop**, I want to take the whole **statuses** string variable that will look like this:

```
{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":1,"m":"1st message"},{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":2,"m":"2nd message"},{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":3,"m":"3rd message"},{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":4,"m":"4th message"}
```

and add to it an object. But not in the front or in the end of it. Inside it. Like this:

```
{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":1,"m":"1st message"},{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":123,"m":"The new message!"},{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":2,"m":"2nd message"},{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":3,"m":"3rd message"},{"p":"1.jpg","s":0,"u":"test","id":4,"m":"4th message"}
```

To cut a long story short, I would like to know if there is any function that adds object(s) next to others by their id.

Example:
statuses.addNewObject(nextToId, value)

Comment: Don't every write your own "JSON" (quotes because yours is invalid) and use `JSON.stringify()` instead.

Comment: Use an array, add the actual objects, insert the _"The new message"_ object at the correct place (`.splice()`) and then use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Oh, no, no. Just, no. Don't try and manually construct JSON -- that way lies madness. Instead, create objects and add them to an array, then it's easy to add a new object to the array. At the end, you can use `JSON.stringify(array)` to get the JSON to send (or in your case `JSON.stringify({action:"Load statuses": statuses })`)

Answer (score -1):

By the code that you show inside `for`, I understand that the value of result has a structure similar to this

```
const result = [
  {
    id: 1,
    poster: "user 1",
    message_text: "message 1",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    poster: "user 2",
    message_text: "message 2",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    poster: "user 3",
    message_text: "message 3",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    poster: "user 4",
    message_text: "message 4",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
];
```

If it is the case, you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), to go through each element of the array and transform it according to the requirement you describe in the code. Please take a look at the following example

```js
const result = [
  {
    id: 1,
    poster: "user 1",
    message_text: "message 1",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    poster: "user 2",
    message_text: "message 2",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    poster: "user 3",
    message_text: "message 3",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    poster: "user 4",
    message_text: "message 4",
    post_type: "post",
    reply_to: "***",
  },
];

const output = result.map((entry) => ({
  p: "1.jpg",
  s: 0,
  u: entry.poster,
  id: entry.id,
  m: entry.message_text,
}));

console.log(output);
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map